# Sum of a fourier series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

$\text{Find the Fouruer series of $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and determine its sum for all |x| $\leq$ $\pi$}$

I found the fourier series. That wasn't the hard part. I got:

$$1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-1}\cos(nx)$$

Which I am fairly confident in.

I'm confused as to how to find the sum of the fourier series though.

I thought I would just take the average of the right and left endpoints and that would be my sum but I am not sure...

Could someone tell me how I would go about finding the sum?

Comment: The keep insight here is to understand WHAT the Fourier series of $f(x)$ is. The series is a representation of $f(x)$ in terms of basis elements of $\cos(nx)$ and $\sin(nx)$. It's similiar to expressing expressing a vector in term of a basis in linear algebra. Well, when is this representation exact? (that is to say $f(x) =$ Fourier Series of $f(x)$). It for the points where $f(x)$ is a continuous function as mentioned in the answer by Stefano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend $f$ to $f^*$: a periodic function of period $2\pi$ which equals $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Then $f^*$ is continuous and so its Fourier series converges pointwise to $f^*$. In particular, the sum of your series is $x \sin x$ for all $x \in[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: I get the fact I have a periodic extension and I find how that converges. Isn't that just 0 then? It seems awfully simple...